# blender make model hair physics ,it show me some odd black things

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]I want to get my Genshin model a physical hair and give it cloth physics.I mean they show something black when the model play animation with physics opened [image: the picture shows the problem]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear.   I'm thinking english is not your primary language.  However perhaps marking up your "odd black things" by putting a circle somewhere on the screen capture may help people help you.

Comment: @james_t: English is not my primary language and I am a blender noob,I have added some new tips about my question.Thanks for answering.